# Round down a double and compare to another number

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am trying to round down a double using Big decimal and then comparing to another number For example:

```
    // Parse the string to extract the double and then put it into Big
    // decimal
    BigDecimal bdAns = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("3.1419"));
    System.out.println(bdAns);
    BigDecimal bdCorr = BigDecimal.valueOf(Double.parseDouble("3.142"));
    System.out.println(bdCorr);
    System.out.println(bdCorr.precision() + " , " + bdAns.precision());
    // Round down the value of the bdAns, so that the precision of bdAns and
    // bdCorr matches. This code doesnt seem to work.
    bdAns = BigDecimal.valueOf(bdAns).setScale(bdCorr.precision(),
            BigDecimal.ROUND_UNNECESSARY);
    System.out.println(bdAns);
    System.out.println(bdAns.compareTo(bdCorr));
```

The last println is printing -1.But they should be equal as 3.1419 round to 3 places after decimal should be 3.142. Can somebody please tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: Unrelated to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184717/hungarian-notation

Comment: I think im reading this correctly but you are comparing 3.1419 to 3.142 and the output is expected a negative integer.  I feel like im reading this wrong.

Comment: I dont use the Hungarian notation,this is something I came up with real fast so please pardon any non-standard java convention or coding styles used

Comment: @Zoop I am expecting both of them to be equal as 3.1419 round to 3 places after decimal should be 3.142

Comment: Thanks that cleared things up for me about your question although im sorry im not sure of the answer :/

Comment: Why parse the string to a double at all? Why not parse directly to a BigDecimal? It's much more accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`precision` and `scale` are not the same thing, it appears you are confusing the two.  `scale` is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point.  `precision` is the total number of digits.

Change all of your references to `precision` to `scale` and it should work (but you'll have to pick a rounding mode other than `UNNECESSARY`).

Comment: Thanks :) I was really confused between precision and scale. Do you know any good site to get more info on this?

Comment: Thanks :) I read that doc but somehow I miised "These scales are the ones used by the methods which return exact arithmetic results..."

Answer (score 2):

Here's an whole example of what you're trying to achieve:

```
import java.math.*;

public class bigdec {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigDecimal dec1 = new BigDecimal("3.1419");
        BigDecimal dec2 = new BigDecimal("3.142");
        System.out.println("first - " + dec1);
        System.out.println("second - " + dec2);
        MathContext mc = new MathContext(dec2.scale() + dec1.toString().indexOf("."));
        dec1 = dec1.round(mc);
        System.out.println("AFTER ROUNDING");
        System.out.println("first - " + dec1);
        System.out.println("second - " + dec2);
        System.out.println(dec1.equals(dec2));
    }

}
```

It rounds `dec1` based on the number of decimal places in `dec2`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use double and long

```
double d1 = 3.1419;
double d2 = 3.142;

long l1 = (long) (d1 * 100);
long l2 = (long) (d2 * 100);

// both l1 and l2 are 314
```

The problem you have is that you are using setScale() of a precision.

```
 bdAns = bdAns.setScale(bdCorr.scale(), BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
```

Comment: the precision of d2 is 4 and precision of d1 is 5. You are not taking into account the precision info. So for numbers like 1234.45678900726244 and 1234.4567890072624, this method might not work. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I assumed you want to compare two numbers based on two decimal places (rounded down)  If this is case, it will make no difference provided the number is less that ~180 million billion. (At this point you can get an overflow with `long`)  I don't see how you want to use precision.